# Converting if else flow from Django to Ruby on Rails

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, django, if-statement

I need to convert this Django If Else flow to Ruby on Rails:

This is the Django code:

```
<select name="level" id="level">

  {% if level == 'gold' %}
    <option value="gold" selected>Gold</option>
  {% else %}
    <option value="gold" >Gold</option>
  {% endif %}

  {% if level == 'silver'%}
    <option value="silver" selected="">Silver</option>
  {% else %}
    <option value="silver" >Silver</option>
  {% endif %}

  % if level == 'bronze' %}
    <option value="bronze" selected="">Bronze</option>
  {% else %}
    <option value="bronze" >Bronze</option>
  {% endif %}

</select>
```

This is the RoR version I did:

```
<select name="level" id="level">

  <% if @package_signup.level == 'gold' %>
    <option value="gold" selected>Gold</option>
  <% else %>
    <option value="gold" >Gold</option>
  <% end %>

  <% if @package_signup.level == 'silver' %>
    <option value="silver" selected="">Silver</option>
  <% else %>
    <option value="silver" >Silver</option>
  <% end %>

  <% if @package_signup.level == 'bronze' %>
    <option value="bronze" selected="">Bronze</option>
  <% else %>
    <option value="bronze" >Bronze</option>
  <% end %>

</select>
```

This is the controller (I'm trying to access the level variable):

```
class Welcome2Controller < ApplicationController
  def pricing
    @package_signup = params[:level] 
  end
end
```

This is the error I receive:

> undefined method `level' for "bronze":String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is because `@package_signup` is an string value which is equal to `params[:level]`. Error message, `undefined method 'level' for "bronze":String` suggests that its value is `bronze`.

You are considering that, probably, as an model object.

Instead of `@package_signup.level== 'gold'` you should use `@package_signup == 'gold'`.

So, your code in view should looks like:

```
<% if @package_signup == 'gold' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using RoR, I suggest you look into `collection_select` (https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select). This would save you a lot of boilerplate code. You can just create an array `[ 'gold', 'silver', 'bronze' ]` and pass the selected value to the `collection_select` function. It will automatically mark the proper option as selected.